# Why my thrift client get such a error "Unknown Source" only under mac os x El Capitan?

Tags: macos, thrift

I test the thrift tutorial under my `Fedora 20` successfully, but when I test under `Mac OS X El Capitan` I get a error as follows:

```
localhost:java abelard$ /usr/bin/java -cp    tutorial.jar:../../lib/java/build/libthrift-0.9.3.jar:../../lib/java/build/lib/*  JavaServer
Starting the simple server...
Starting the secure server...
```

Then I open another terminal:

```
localhost:java abelard$ /usr/bin/java -cp tutorial.jar:../../lib/java/build/libthrift-0.9.3.jar:../../lib/java/build/lib/*  JavaClient simple
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:132)
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86)
at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:429)
at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:318)
at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:219)
at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:77)
at tutorial.Calculator$Client.recv_ping(Unknown Source)
at tutorial.Calculator$Client.ping(Unknown Source)
at JavaClient.perform(Unknown Source)
at JavaClient.main(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error that you are receiving is not "Unknown Source"... that text in the stack trace is telling you that it doesn't know what line in the source code the method call came from.  That happens because your classes must not be compiled with debugging information (to remedy try passing the -g flag to javac when you compile).

The error you are experiencing looks like it is some networking or other I/O error but it is not clear from the stack trace what it could be.

Comment: @@bcg, thank you, but I don't understand you clearly, I guess this error is relative to Mac os X, because it works fine under my Fedora